# Does 1,3-dichloroallene possess a C2 symmetry axis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, symmetry, allenes

> Is there an $C_2$ axis of symmetry in $\ce{Cl-CH=C=CH-Cl}$?
>   [image: 1,3-dichloroallene]

A $C_2$ axis of symmetry means that I should be able to rotate the molecule about an axis by $180^\circ$. But I would need a composition of the following two rotations

1. $90^\circ$ rotation about $\ce{C=C=C}$ axis
2. $180^\circ$ about the perpendicular bisector of $\ce{C=C=C}$.

Would that count as a $C_2$ axis of rotation?

Comment: The rule is that the molecule must be indistinguishable before and after the symmetry operation. Therefore is not the C$_2$ axis  a line from the midpoint between the two Cl atoms  (or H atoms) to the central C atom ? The only other operations are E and S$_4$

Comment: Sometimes, the perfectly OK and preferred formula does not help. In this case it's useful to draw it with 4 stereochem. wedges insted of 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A $C_2$ axis is indeed here—although not the one that you are thinking of: your suggestion of a $C_4$ then $C_2$ rotation does not qualify as a $C_2$ symmetry operation. There is a true $C_2$ axis which bisects the allene and is tilted by $45^\circ$ from both the $\ce{Cl-C-Cl}$ and $\ce{H-C-H}$ planes.

One can visualize symmetry elements for small molecules using, for example, [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/).
Launch the program GUI and do the following:

1. *File* → *Get MOL*
2. Type in an identifier, e.g. the name, `1,3-dichloropropa-1,2-diene`, or CAS number, `83682-32-0`.
3. Open console (*File* → *Console*) and enter `show pointgroup` to list symmetry elements and `draw pointgroup` to add them to the picture:
   [image: Jmol GUI]
   [image: animated rotation around C2 axis in 3D]